# Agile toolkit ui with eclipse oxygen

Tags: eclipse-oxygen, agiletoolkit

Hi i am a beginner in php. i have able to successfully run my hello world program with eclipse oxygen and php builtin server. 
I want to use agile ui in my current php project. i am putting the agile toolkit folder in my project folder. and when i write this code.

```
<?php
    echo "Hello my first page from php"; // Hello world run perfectly
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';           // no error here

    $app = new \atk4\ui\App('My First App'); // Error
    $app->initLayout('Centered');            

    $app->add('HelloWorld');    
?>
```

it is giving me error "App cannot be resolved to a type"
can anyone tell what to do because i didn't find a way to make it work?

Comment: Solved this problem by adding the path of agile toolkit in eclipse project